# How can I test web push notifications in rails 6?

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I'd like to test push notifications in a rails app, which I send by ActionCable. I'm using rspec.

- How do I test that are received by certain users?
- Can I test it with capybara?
- Can I write system-testing for it?
- Can I test it with rspec?
- Do I need to install JS testing?
- Any other info I might need to have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can test the behaviors that ActionCable implements with Capybara in system tests/specs, and/or you can test them at a lower level with RSpec channel specs - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/channel-specs, https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/matchers/have-broadcasted-matcher, https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/matchers/have-stream-from-matcher. System tests will often require you to use multiple Capybara sessions, depending on what exact behaviors you're testing - see Capybara#using_session.

Comment: But is it there a way to test web push notifications with capybara?

Comment: @ChiaraAni Yes - as explained in my answer - did you read the info in the links?